# You cannot edit this page... please contact your Administrator

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

We can't edit pages within our network unless we reload the page (`.../my/_layouts/15/sharpoint.aspx`) on our SharePoint 2019 host. We have to reload it every day.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to edit the application pages in `_layouts` location.